# laplace inverse transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

So I have have an equation and I need to do laplace inverse transformation  $$ I(s)=\frac{s}{7s+6} $$ and then for partial fractions I got $$ I(s)=1/7-\frac{6}{49s+42}$$ and now for inverse transform I have $$I(t)=\frac{-6}{49}*e^{-(6t/7)}+\frac{1}{7}$$
I can't get the right answers with this so can somebody tell me is the transformation done wrong
                                                                          or is just my starting values wrong

Comment: everything seems right except \$1/7\delta(t)\$ will be there instead of only 1/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$I(s)=\frac{s}{7s+6}\$

Multiply by \$\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{7}}\$

\$I(s)=\frac{1}{7}\frac{s}{s+\frac{6}{7}}\$

Move out s from the numerator so we got a 1 there so we can use the laplace transform of \$\frac{1}{s+a}\mathcal{L}e^{-at}\$

\$I(s)=s\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{s+\frac{6}{7}}\$

So a factor s in laplace domain is a derivation in time domain, a factor \$\frac{1}{7}\$ is just a scaling, the last factor is the \$e^{-at}\$

The answer is the derivative of this expression: \$\frac{1}{7}e^{-\frac{6t}{7}}\$

I will let you do that step so I don't take all the glory.

---

Here's a [link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7Bs%7D%7Bs%2Ba%7D) if you need more help.

Comment: But the LT of \$-\frac {6}{49}e^{-\frac{6t}{7}}\$ is not \$\frac{s}{7s+6}\$

Comment: @Chu I assume you didn't click the link for more help. I will copy paste the important part. "*Evaluate \$e^{-at}\$ at point 0 = 1 => \$-ae^{-at}+1\$*". Lo and behold. I got all the glory.

Comment: It depends on whether \$i(t)\$ has a step at \$t=0\$; there are two possible solutions if this condition is not specified.

Comment: @Chu Then supply your answer and take all the glory.